# Allow html in an <a> tag title attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe, tooltip

I have tried to find a solution to this problem and so far I have come up with this pipe that should allow HTML

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: "toHtml"
})
export class ToHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(content) {
        return `<b>${content}</b>`;
    }
}
```

I have a link, which displays a data tool tip on hover:

```
<a *ngIf="day.Info.Info" data-toggle="tooltip" [title]="day.Info.Info | toHtml" placement="right"><i style="color:black" class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></a>
```

However, this is the result I get:

[image]

So the pipe isn't working and afaik I can't use `[innerHtml]=""` since it just changes the link to the string, not the icon.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: an elements title attribute can contain what looks like HTML, ie.`<b>blah</b>` but it's not treated as HTML

Comment: native `title` attribute maintain only text, to have custom hint, you need to implement it or use some plugin that implements such thing

Comment: @JaromandaX: That depends entirely on what the attribute's value is used for. Yes, it's not treated as HTML by the standard tooltip handling of the `title` attribute in browsers. But anything else (like Bootstrap) can do what it wants.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 Documentation says that you can include HTML in the title attribute, as Nicolas is trying to do. That's not the issue here; https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#interactive-demo

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - indeed, I should've said *an elements **title** attribute*

Comment: @thebluefox I've just noticed your link, and simply adding `data-html="true"` the the `<a>` worked, I didn't know this was possible with bootstrap! My apologies!

Comment: Please post the working solution as an answer to your own question, so that other people running into a similar issue can find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comments, looking at the Bootstrap documentation for Tooltips;

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#interactive-demo

> And with custom HTML added:
>
> `<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">
>     Tooltip with HTML
>   </button>`

You require the `data-html="true"` attribute to be placed on the `<a>` element.